# Need assistance updating PHP script with method or case statement

Tags: php, postfix-mta

This script checks the modified date on a Postfix mailbox folder.

The issue is, I have more than one location that needs to be check.

Folder **/mnt/mail1/** contains mail dirs a,b,d,g

Folder **/mnt/mail2/** contains the rest **c,e,f,h,........,x,z**

The script is run simply via the URL https://URL/index.php?email=charlie@delta.com

I need the script to check in the correct mount point depending on the email address being checked. In the case above it should check in /mnt/mail2/d/e/delta.com/.....

Please help. I know 0 to nothing about php.

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST["email"])) {
    $emailaddress= trim($_REQUEST["email"]);
    $emailparts = explode("@",$emailaddress);
    if (sizeof($emailparts) != 2) {
            print "invalid-email,,,,";
            exit();
    }
    $username = $emailparts[0];
    $domain = $emailparts[1];      
    $basedir = "/mnt/mail1/";
    $livePrefix = $basedir;
    $archivePrefix = $basedir."archive/";
    $livePath = $livePrefix . substr($domain,0,1) . "/" . substr($domain,1,1) . "/" . $domain . "/" . substr($username,0,1) . "/" .  $username;
    $archivePath = $archivePrefix . $domain ;
    $liveStat = stat( $livePath . "/" . "cur");
    $archStat = false;
    if ( file_exists( $archivePath ) && is_dir( $archivePrefix ) ) {
            $arhiveDirs = scandir($archivePath);
            foreach( $arhiveDirs  as $i => $fname ) {
                    if ( stripos( $fname , $username . "-"  ) !== false ) {
                            $archivePath = $archivePath . "/" . $fname ;
                            $archStat = stat( $archivePath . "/cur" );
                            break;
                    }
            }
    }
    $status="lost" ;
    if ( $liveStat != false ) {
            $status = "live" . "," .  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $liveStat['mtime'] ) . "," . sizeof( scandir($livePath . "/new") ) . "," ;
    } else if ($archStat != false ) {
            $status = "archived,,,";
    } else {
            $status = "lost,,,";
    }

    if ($archStat != false ) {
            $status = $status .  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $archStat['mtime'] ) . "," . sizeof( scandir($archivePath . "/new") )  ;
    } else {
            $status = $status .  "," ;
    }

    print $status ;
    exit();
} else {
    print "error,,,,";
    exit();
}


?>
```

Comment: And you believe that we are willing to spend our time to implement what you want? Take a book, learn PHP and if you have a special problem, we are here to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Without reading the code and knowing much about php: First, you need to get the email address from the link. Use regex for this.
Second, explode the email and get the domain (also with regex).

$domain =

Get the first and the second character of the domain: $domain[0] and $domain[1].

Then you should choose between the two folders two check. Do it with a switch, with 4 main cases: a, b, d, g and a default case that checks the others.

... by the way: shouldn't the case above check the /mnt/mail1/ folder?

Comment: I does check the mail1 folder, but I need to check the other as well. 
Your answer does sound like it would work, but remember.....Me and PHP aren't friends.

Is it possible that you can update that code for me please

Comment: Sorry, I would, but I don't know much about PHP either.

Comment: No prob. Thanks anyway. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the script has everything you need ready:

```
$domain = $emailparts[1];      
$basedir = "/mnt/mail1/";
```

you just need to alter the `$basedir` according to the value in `$domain`, for example by

```
switch ($domain[0]) {
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
    case 'd':
    case 'g':
       // fall through: all the cases above reach this point
       $basedir = "/mnt/mail1/";
       break;
    default:
       // all other cases are handled here
       $basedir = "/mnt/mail2/";
 }
```

but seriously, if you want to maintain such scripts, you should learn the basics. It can be dangerous to just copy/paste code lines from some random strangers on the net. And especially on Stackoverflow, which is a Q and A site, people are usually not willing to just write code